# Regular Expressions: Search in list

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter strings in a list based on a regular expression.

Is there something better than `[x for x in list if r.match(x)]` ?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can create an **iterator** in Python 3.x or a **list** in Python 2.x by using:

```
filter(r.match, list)
```

To convert the Python 3.x *iterator* to a list, simply cast it; `list(filter(..))`.

Comment: Actually, list comprehensions are usually prefered over functional constructs such as filter, reduce, lambda, etc.

Comment: @Ivo: They are usually preferred because they're usually clearer and often more succinct. However in this case, the `filter` version is perfectly clear and has much less noise.

Comment: what is `r.match` here?

Comment: @rbatt `r.match` is a method that, when applied to a given string,  finds whether the regex `r` matches that string (and returns a corresponding match object if so, but that doesn't matter in this case as we just care whether the result is truthy)

Comment: Can anybody put example? Where to pass search mask?

Comment: First `import re`, second create your regex `r = re.compile(".*cat")`

Answer (score 293):

**Full Example (Python 3):**
**For Python 2.x look into Note below**

```
import re

mylist = ["dog", "cat", "wildcat", "thundercat", "cow", "hooo"]
r = re.compile(".*cat")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, mylist)) # Read Note below
print(newlist)
```

Prints:

```
['cat', 'wildcat', 'thundercat']
```

---

**Note:**

For Python 2.x developers, [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) returns a list already. In [Python 3.x `filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) was changed to return an iterator so it has to be converted to `list` (in order to see it printed out nicely).

[Python 3 code example](http://rextester.com/RDBZLH81559) 
[Python 2.x code example](http://rextester.com/YTISE81276)

Comment: Hi there, When I run the above code, I get `<filter object at 0x1057acda0>` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to python docs (python 2.7.12): https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter
filter returns a list not an object.
You can also check that code:  https://repl.it/X3G/5786  (just hit run)

Comment: Thank you. I am using Python 3.5.2 on a Mac. I tried your link. Of course it works, though not sure why I get that msg. I even removed the `str` since `filter` returns a list anyway, to no avail...

Comment: @joshua you've probably figured this out by now but try `print(list(newlist))` or `print([i for i in newlist])`

Comment: This is ridiculously difficult. This is why R is superior. Simply grep(pattern, vector_of_names)

Comment: How do you do this without compiling the regex first? Like `re.match(".*cat", my_string)`.

Comment: filter(..) call does that internally. we are passing the r.match (pointer to a funciton) and a list of strings to match to.

Comment: How would you do this with a regex grouping, when `p = re.compile(r'/simple/(.*)/')`?

Comment: I dont suppose theres a way to also include the index?

Comment: you probably want to use `r.search` instead of match

Answer (score 10):

To do so without compiling the Regex first, use a `lambda` function - for example:

```py
from re import match

values = ['123', '234', 'foobar']
filtered_values = list(filter(lambda v: match('^\d+$', v), values))

print(filtered_values)
```

Returns:

```py
['123', '234']
```

`filter()` just takes a `callable` as it's first argument, and returns a list where that callable returned a 'truthy' value.