# Python regular expression to match an integer as string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter a list of strings with regular expressions, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list). However the code gives an unexpected result:

```
In [123]: r = re.compile('[0-9]*')
In [124]: string_list = ['123', 'a', '467','a2_2','322','21']
In [125]: filter(r.match, string_list)
Out[125]: ['123', 'a', '467', 'a2_2', '322_2', '21']
```

I expected the output to be `['123', '467', '21']`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern contains the `*`, quantifier, will match *zero* or more digits. So even if the string doesn't contain a digit at all, it will match the pattern. Furthermore, your pattern will match digits wherever they occur in the input string, meaning, `a2` is still a valid match because it *contains* a digit.

Try using this pattern

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Or more simply:

```
^\d+$
```

This will match one or more digits. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors ensure that no *other* characters will be allowed within the string.

Answer (score 8):

Is there really a need for Regex here?  You have [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> string_list = ['123', 'a', '467','a2_2','322','21']
>>> [x for x in string_list if x.isdigit()]
['123', '467', '322', '21']
>>>
```

Comment: In this specific example, no there isn't, but I wanted to know why it wasn't working the way I expected.

Comment: What will happen with let's say `1e6`? :)

Comment: @Allendar `>>> '23e1'.isdigit()` is `False`

Comment: @Allendar - Yes, that will fail. :)  However, judging by his original Regex pattern, it doesn't look like the OP has numbers like that.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I guess it's nice for variation too to see different approaches as a solution :). Btw 1e6 seems to return a float here in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: i am a bit confused about pythons definition of 'digit' `"23".isdigit()` would be false in my understandings of a 'digit' because "23" actually are two digits. I would expect this to be true only for strings that match the pattern `^[0-9]$`.