# Python: find exact word in list

Tags: python, regex, list

**Set-up**

I have the following dictionary,

```
d={'City':['Paris', 'Berlin','Rome', 'London']}
```

and the following one-element list,

```
 address=['Bedford Road, London NW7']
```

---

**Problem**

I want to check if one of the cities is in the address.

---

**Tried so far**

*(1)*

```
for x in d['City']:
  if x in address:
    print('yes')
  else: 
    print('no')
```

only prints `no`.

*(2)*

```
for x in d['City']:
  r = re.compile(x)
  newlist = list(filter(r.match, address))
```

gives a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Got this one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593126/7326714) which seems to be what should solve this, but the error doesn't help.

How do I go about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution #1 was actually quite close, but it doesn't work, because `address` is a list of string, not a string itself.

So, it will work perfectly fine, if you just take first element of list `address` i.e. `address[0]`.

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
>>> any(i in address[0] for i in d['City'] )
True
```

For code snippet, you can use:

```
if any(i in address[0] for i in d['City'] ):
    print 'Yes'
else:
    print 'No'
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Switching to your slick alternative though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since your address is a one-element list, you should check `address[0]` instead of `address`:

```
for x in d['City']:
    if x in address[0]:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't increasing the size of the list:

```
for x in d['City']:
    if x in address[0]:
        print('yes')
    else: 
        print('no')
```

Comment: You do not need to use split, you can remove it and it will continue to work.

Comment: To improve your post you could improve your explanation.