# If statement that keeps characters only

Tags: python, string, if-statement, letter

Let's say we have a list `list_a = [a,b,C,.,/,!,d,E,f,]`

I want to append to a new list only the letters of the alphabet.

So the new list will be list_b = [a,b,C,d,E,f].
So far I have tried the following:

```
list_b = []
for elements in list_a:
    try:
        if elements == str(elements):
            list_b.append(elements)
    except ValueError: #Catches the Error when the element is not a letter
        continue
```

However, when I print the list_b it has all the elements of `list_a`, it doesn't do the job I expected. Also, a comma in the example above brings an error.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list) help?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this code would work? I'm not understanding your logic.

Comment: Simple.If the element of the list is a letter/character it gets appended in a new list else the for loop goes on.What do you not understand ?

Comment: I can't understand why you would think that `str('.')` does not equal `'.'`, or what would raise a ValueError.

Comment: You are right.str( 3 ) is not equal ' 3 '.Allthough this works for numbers it doesn't works for commas , questionmarks etc.I am new to Pytho sorry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method of the string type.

```
In [1]: list_a = ['a','b','C','.','/','!','d','E','f']

In [2]: list_b = [i for i in list_a if i.isalpha()]

In [3]: list_b
Out[3]: ['a', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E', 'f']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking if the character is an alphabet by using the .isalpha() function.

```
list_b = []
for elements in list_a:
   if elements.isalpha():
        list_b.append(elements)
```

Comment: Sorry. Got confused with Java

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the fact that the str() function does not return the "str" elements you think it does, just an str representation of them. 
Try creating a list with you dictionary [a-zA-Z] (not very pythonic but simple to grasp) and check if your character exists in it.
I suggest writing your own code from scratch instead of copy/pasting, that is the only way to really understand the problem....

Comment: Thanks for letting me know my mistake.I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is basically the same logic of using `isalpha()` method, but you can do this by using `filter`:

```
list_a = ['a','b','C','.','/','!','d','E','f']

list_b = list(filter(lambda i: i.isalpha(), list_a))

print(list_b)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E', 'f']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import string
for item in list_a:
    if item in string.ascii_letters:
        list_b.append(item)
```

Also, check out the [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module. It has a lot of additional methods that can help you, should you wish to work with strings. Do note that this works only with ascii characters. If you want to check for every character in an alphabet, then you can via the `isalpha()` method, as the others have noted above.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `string` or `re` package to do this

```
import re
new_list = [c for c in old_list if re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]', c)]
```

Or with `string`

```
import string
new_list = [c for c in old_list if c in string.ascii_letters]
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @DanielRoseman They're single line statements with a single if test, I'm not sure how much simpler they can get.

Comment: Why re? for such a small thing.

Comment: stick to KISS rule

Comment: Works fine.However kerk12's answer is much simpler and faster.Thanks anyway !