# Return list of comments with list of words in list of sentences

Tags: python, regex

I have a long (1.5m) list of sentences and a similarly long list of words that I am looking for within the list of sentences. For example:

```
list_of_words = ['Turin', 'Milan']
list_of_sents = ['This is a sent about turin.', 'This is a sent about manufacturing.']
```

I would like to have a function that is able to return those sentences that contain the target word without alphanumeric characters next to them. In other words, only the first of the sentences above should match.

I have developed the function below but it takes too long to parse through each the millions of words and sentences. I was wondering if there is a package or alternative that could mitigate this computational intensity.

```
def find_target_sents(list_of_words, list_of_sents):
     target_sents = []
     i, j = 0, 0
     word_len = len(list_of_words)
     sent_len = len(list_of_sents)
     for word in list_of_words:
        i += 1
        for sent in list_of_sents:
            j += 1
            print('%s out of %s words and %s out of %s sentences' % (j, word_len , i, sent_len))
            match = re.compile(r'\%s\b' % word, re.I)
            y = match.search(sent)
            if y != None:
                print(sent)
                t = (word, sentence)
                target_sent.append(t)
     print(target_sent)
```

Comment: Can the target word ever be _within_ a word, or will it always be its own word, i.e. `ear` vs `pearl`?

Comment: Ideally it would be it's own word, ear should not match pearl nor should Turin match manufacturing

Comment: Your code seems wrong: you have 2 `for` loops on list_of_sents and nothing for list_of_words

Comment: thank you! I have amended the code to reflect this.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with nltk, tag removed. Also, to just build a regex with alternations and word boundaries, you may [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3). To make the pattern dynamically, use `re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(list_of_words)))`. Do not add `.*` before and after unless you plan to use the regex match to get the whole string/line, but note it will be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you could build a string with all the words to search from list_of_words like `(Turin|Milan)`
, you could do a regex match on:

```
^.*\b(Turin|Milan)\b.*$
```

Also, we could avoid both the for loops, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list#answer-39593126).

Comment: Thanks! How could I edit this to join thousands of words to potentially match on?

Comment: Try this: `'|'.join(list_of_words)`

Answer (score 0):

Could just build sets and use their constant time membership check:

```
from string import punctuation

def find_target_sents(words, sents):
    # translation table
    table = str.maketrans('', '', punctuation) 
    # hold found sentences by word
    found = {word: [] for word in words} 
    # make unique sets for each sentence and remove punctuation
    parsed = [set(sent.translate(table).split()) for sent in sents]
    # check
    for word in found:
        for sent in parsed:
            if word in sent:
                found[word].append(sent)
```

Basically this assumes your sentences follow English grammar and are separated with spaces following a chracter or punctionation (assuming another word will follow of course).

It takes each sentence and removes any punctuation from it, then splits on whitespace and turns the result into a `set` which has constant time, O(1), membership check.

So the sentence: `"I, want to go, to Burger King!"` ...

... becomes `('I', 'want', 'to', 'go', 'Burger', 'King')`; where only unique elements exist!

Obviously there are issues if you are looking for `'Burger King'` but thats technically two words...

Comment: This is the most efficient approach, by far. However, your translation table should replace each punctuation char by whitespace, instead of None, to correctly deal with cases like "foo:bar" (without space around ':')