# fastest and elegant way to check whether a given list contains some element by regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Fastest and elegant way to check whether some element expressed by regular expression is in a given list.

For example: 
given a list:

```
newlist = ['this','thiis','thas','sada']
regex = re.compile('th.s')
```

In this question: [Regular Expressions: Search in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list)

```
list(filter(regex.match,newlist))
```

give me a list

```
['this','thas']
```

However, I just want to return **True or False**. Therefore above method is not efficient since it looks through all element of newlist. Is there a way like

```
'this' in newlist
```

to efficiently and elegantly check whether some element expressed by regular expression is in a given list.

Comment: Using `regex` in the first place is maybe not the most efficient method...

Comment: Use `any()` rather than `filter()`?

Comment: Make a single string out of _newlist_: `,this,thiis,thas,sada,`. Keep it, then run a _findall()_, or a single match using a new constructed regex `,(th.s),`. This will give you the `['this','thas']` or TRUE/FALSE without having to iterate.

Comment: @Loocid Do you mean any(filter(regex.match,newlist))? It still looks through all element of newlist to return "True or False", right?

Comment: @Loocid Do you mean in python3 the filter() gives me a iterator not a full list, therefore when I composite any(), if it's not the worst case, it will not go through all element of newlist to return True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Loocid suggested, you can use `any`. I would do it with a generator expression like so:

```
newlist = ['this','thiis','thas','sada']
regex = re.compile('th.s')

result = any(regex.match(word) for word in newlist)
print(result) # True
```

Here is another version with `map` that is slightly faster:

```
result = any(map(regex.match, newlist))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, I have a question :  Does any(filter(regex.match,newlist)) has the same effect as your code? Since I just read in python3 filter gives an iterator not a full list.

Comment: @maplemaple Yes, but essentially all you are doing with that is checking if the length of `filter(regex.match,newlist)` is greater that 0. I think my version is a bit more explicit.

Comment: @maplemaple FYI, I added a slightly faster version with `map`.

Comment: There is one more problem. If I give `regex = re.compile('th.')`, result should be `False` since `'th.'` not in the list. But the code is still `True`

Comment: @maplemaple Add `$` to your regex to make it `'th.$'`. `$` means end of string.

Answer (score 1):

This will evaluate the list until it finds the first match.

```
def search_for_match(list):
    result = False
    for i in newlist:
        if bool(re.match(r"th.s", i)) is True:
            result = True
            break
    return result
```

Or to make it more general:

```
def search_for_match(list, pattern):
    result = False
    for i in list:
        if bool(re.match(pattern, i)) is True:
            result = True
            break
    return result

newlist = ['this','thiis','thas','sada']
found = search_for_match(newlist, r"th.s")
print(found) # True
```

Just for kicks I ran these through the timer. I sooo lost:

```
t = time.process_time()
newlist = ['this','thiis','thas','sada']
search_for_match(newlist, r"th.s")
elapsed_time1 = time.process_time() - t
print(elapsed_time1) # 0.00015399999999998748

t2 = time.process_time()
newlist = ['this','thiis','thas','sada']
regex = re.compile('th.s')
result = any(regex.match(word) for word in newlist)
elapsed_time2 = time.process_time() - t2
print(elapsed_time2) # 1.1999999999900979e-05

t3 = time.process_time()
newlist = ['this','thiis','thas','sada']
regex = re.compile('th.s')
result = any(map(regex.match, newlist))
elapsed_time3 = time.process_time() - t3
print(elapsed_time3) # 5.999999999950489e-06
```

Comment: @Tomothy32, I ran them through a timer cause I was curious, not because I didn't believe you. Wow is mine slow.

Comment: @CarlBrubaker No problem. By the way, you're skewing the results by timing everything, not just that one line of code. You should only be timing `search_for_match(newlist, r"th.s")`, `result = any(regex.match(word) for word in newlist)`, and `result = any(map(regex.match, newlist))` individually. The `timeit` module is also a better idea, as it repeats tests more than once and is more accurate in general. Also, as a side note, you can speed up your function by precompiling the regex.

Comment: There is one more problem. If I give `regex = re.compile('th.')`, result should be `False` since `'th.'` not in the list. But the code is still `True`

Answer (score 0):

I can think of (besides using any)

```
next((x for x in newlist if regex.match(x)), False)
```

Does not return True but probably OK for conditional testing if you have no empty strings :)