# fast regex matching in list

Tags: python, regex, suffix-tree, suffix-array

[Regular Expressions: Search in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list)

I want to have a fast way to match a regex in a list. The above solution has a linear complexity wrt the length of the list. Given things like suffix-array or suffix-tree for pure string search, is there something similar for regex search in a list that can have a sublinear complexity in the length of the list? (I am currently interested in a python solution. Solutions in other langauges can be mentioned, but not a priority here.) Thanks.

Comment: Just making sure: you've already pre-compiled and pre-optimized your regex patterns and still the performance is too low for you?

Comment: My question is that the solution should have a sublinear time complexity wrt the list length. No matter how you optimize the regex, the current solution has a linear complexity wrt the length of the list, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: When you say "sublinear", you mean faster than O(n) using "Big O notation" where n is the size of the list?

Comment: What would the regex consist of ? If you're searching using a string literal that is exactly one of the elements, it can be done a different way. Set up a full blown trie of all the elements of the array, then just search using the term. Would consist of a max of 5 comparisons to match or fail, no matter how many elements there are.

Comment: Not in the general case. Matching a single character in a list can't be done in sublinear time. And this is a (very simple) regex.