# regular expressions search list, but return list of same size

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-re

Similar to this question: [Regular Expressions: Search in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640359/regular-expressions-search-in-list)

But I'd like to return a list of the same size of the searched list, with `None` or `''` where there are no matches:

```
import re

mylist = ["dog", "cat", "wildcat", "thundercat", "cow", "hooo"]
r = re.compile(".*cat")
list(filter(r.match, mylist)) 

# looking for  ["", "cat", "wildcat", "thundercat", "", ""]
```

I tried removing `filter` but that returns the whole list

Also tried

```
[r.match(x) for x in mylist]
```

but this returns:

```
[None,
 <regex.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='cat'>,
 <regex.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='wildcat'>,
 <regex.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='thundercat'>,
 None,
 None]
```

And I don't know how to extract the strings

`.group(0)` throws an error for `None`

Either method works, preference to what is faster/more efficient as the list will be a long one

Comment: Is regex mandatory for your application ?

Comment: no, not at all.. just seemed like a simple approach from the linked question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
[m.group(0) if m else "" for m in map(r.match, mylist)]
```

Produces:

```
['', 'cat', 'wildcat', 'thundercat', '', '']
```

Answer (score 7):

A non-regex solution should also be fine.

If you want the string to end with `cat`, you can use `str.endswith`:

```py
>>> [x if x.endswith('cat') else '' for x in mylist]
['', 'cat', 'wildcat', 'thundercat', '', '']
```

If `cat` can appear anywhere in the string, you can use `in` operator:

```py
>>> [x if 'cat' in x else '' for x in mylist]
['', 'cat', 'wildcat', 'thundercat', '', '']
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use an alternation in regex to get empty match for a non-match:

```sh
import re

mylist = ["dog", "cat", "wildcat", "thundercat", "cow", "hooo"]
rx = re.compile(r'.*cat|^')

print( [rx.findall(i)[0] for i in mylist] )
```

Regex `.*cat|^` matches a string that has `cat` or just the line start to make sure empty match when `cat` is not matched.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fg6how/1)

**Output:**

```
['', 'cat', 'wildcat', 'thundercat', '', '']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `and x` to your almost working attempt:

```
[r.match(x) and x for x in mylist]
```

Result:

```
[None, 'cat', 'wildcat', 'thundercat', None, None]
```

Or

```
[m(x) and x for x in mylist]
```

after `m = r.match`.